# app crashes on loading default realm after a migration

Tags: realm

Realm 0.95.0 sometimes crashes when loading the default Realm following a migration. This happens infrequently, and we haven't yet been able to reproduce it in a debugging environment. We are using Realm-Cocoa, but calling from a Swift endpoint.

```
    var config = RLMRealmConfiguration.defaultConfiguration()
    config.schemaVersion = 3
    config.migrationBlock = { (migration, oldVersion) -> Void in
      ...
    }

    RLMRealmConfiguration.setDefaultConfiguration(config)
    RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
```

Here is the backtrace

```
0x100313ae0 [void realm::util terminate&lt;unsigned long, unsigned long&gt;(char const*, char const*, long, unsigned long, unsigned long) ] (terminate.hpp:45)
...
...
0x10030c44c [realm::SharedGroup SharedGroup(realm::Replication&amp;, realm::SharedGroup::DurabilityLevel, char const*) ] (group_shared.hpp:975)
0x1003073a0 [RLMRealm initWithPath:key:readOnly:inMemory:dynamic:error:] (RLMRealm.mm:235)
0x10030821c [RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:error:] (RLMRealm.mm:400)
0x100307a98 [RLMRealm defaultRealm] (RLMRealm.mm:302)
...
```

Is there anything we can do to safeguard against this crash? Does the migration function need to be wrapped in an autoreleasepool block, as per issue [#1589](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1589)?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you see `realm::util terminate` in your stack trace, it's likely because an internal consistency assertion in Realm has failed, and generally indicates either a corrupt file or a bug in Realm itself. If you have access to the device logs (for example if you received this crash report using a service like Crashlytics or Hockey), you should see a message printed by the assertion failure.

The best thing you can do in these cases is to report the issue to the realm team (help@realm.io) with as much information as possible to allow us to reproduce the issue, and investigate further. We're generally pretty responsive.